# Entity not updating in database using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, put

I am creating an API for my Xamarin Android application and I have created this method to update password in the database:

```
[HttpPut]
[ActionName("updatepassword")]
public HttpResponseMessage updatepassword(string password,string email)
{
    user_table user = dbe.user_table
                         .Where(x => x.email_address == email)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
    user.password_hash = password.GetHashCode();

    var response = dbe.SaveChanges();
    string finalresponse = "password updated successfully" + response;

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, finalresponse );
}
```

But when I test it using postman it shows that 0 entities have been affected.

I also tried using

```
dbe.user_table.AddorUpdate()
```

but it doesn't work either, please help me.

This is my postman query

```
http://192.168.10.9:8044/api/account/updatepassword/?password=asad1234&email=asadregards@gmail.com
```

I have published my API on IIS Server that is why I am using IP Address instead of localhost.

Comment: @marc_s you should have answered my query after editing my question

Comment: Probably state of entity is not changed. Did you try to use [EntityStates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state)?

Comment: If there were an obvious answer, I would have posted it. The only thing obvious is that you should **always** check for `NULL` after calling `.FirstOrDefault()` before any further operation: `if (user != null) { ...... }` - otherwise you'll be possibly trying to set the `password_hash` and end up with a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Which state does EF say the entity is in _before_ you call `SaveChanges`? Check `dbe.ChangeTracker.Entries()`

Comment: @AsadUllah Don't expect miracles, at least not from us, when posting code in which nothing is obviously wrong and about which you don't supply any details, like what you see when you debug it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
var user = dbe.user_table
            .Where(x => x.email_address == email)
             .FirstOrDefault();

var response=0;
if (user!=null)
{
   user.password_hash = password.GetHashCode();
 dbe.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

// Or you can try 
//dbe.Entry(user).Property(i => i.password_hash).IsModified = true;

    response = dbe.SaveChanges();
}
 
........
........
```

And maybe it's a good idea  to change you API header too:

```
[Route("updatepassword/{password}/{email}")]
public  IHttpActionResult updatepassword(string password,string email)
{
.........
.......
return response>0 ? Ok():BadRequest();

}
```

Comment: It's not at all clear why marking the entire `user` object as `Modified` would solve this issue. It's less efficient because in the original code only `user.password_hash` should be marked as modified, and updated. And if the original code doesn't work, there's no reason to believe that this answer would really solve the issue.

Comment: As you know DB can't update just one field. It always updates the whole record, or sometimes the whole pages of records.

Comment: Physical aspects of database updates are irrelevant here. *Logically* only one fields needs to be updated. What matters most here is that the issue isn't clarified. If it works now it's probably because they changed more than just this.

Comment: I've made some changes. Check my answer pls.